# How can I improve my cellForRowAt function?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I have read that the `cellForRowAt` method should not be to resource-intensive as it is called frequently while a user is scrolling through a `TableView` I tried to limit how much went into my `cellForRowAt` but seem to have overused it because anytime it is called scrolling is interrupted as it loads more data.

Here is my function:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print(indexPath)
        var post: PostStruct
        var peopleUserIsFollowing: [String] = []
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
        cell.delegate = self
        if postArray.count == 0 {
            let instructions = cell.textLabel
            instructions?.text = "Press the camera to start Piking!"
            instructions?.textAlignment = .center
            clearPosts(cell)
        }else {
            post = postArray[indexPath.row]
            if let leftPostArray = userDefaults.array(forKey: fbLeftKey) as? [String]{
                votedLeftPosts = leftPostArray
            }
            if let rightPostArray = userDefaults.array(forKey: fbRightKey) as? [String]{
                votedRightPosts = rightPostArray
            }
            
            let firstReference = storageRef.child(post.firstImageUrl)
            let secondReference = storageRef.child(post.secondImageUrl)
            
            
            cell.firstImageView.sd_setImage(with: firstReference)
            cell.secondImageView.sd_setImage(with: secondReference)
            
            
            
            //For FriendsTableView query
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            let followingReference = db.collection("following")
                .document(currentUser!)
                .collection("UserIsFollowing")
            followingReference.getDocuments(){(querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        peopleUserIsFollowing.append(document.documentID)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            //Fill in labels and imageViews
            
            cell.timer = createTimer(post, cell)
            
            cell.leftTitle.text = post.firstTitle
            cell.rightTitle.text = post.secondTitle
            
            cell.postDescription.text = post.postDescription
            if post.userPic == "" {
                userPic =
                    "Placeholder"
            } else{
                userPic = post.userPic
            }
            let url = URL(string: userPic)
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
            cell.profilePic.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            
            let votesCollection = db.collection("votes").document(post.postID)
            getCount(ref: votesCollection, cell: cell)
            
            if(post.uid != currentUser){
                cell.userName.text = post.poster
            }else{
                cell.userName.text = "Me"
                cell.tapLeft.isEnabled = false
                cell.tapRight.isEnabled = false
            }
            cell.textLabel?.text = ""
            
            if(post.poster == Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid || post.endDate - Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970) <= 0){
                cell.tapRight.isEnabled = false
                cell.tapLeft.isEnabled = false
                cell.firstImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
                cell.secondImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
            }
            else if(votedRightPosts.contains(post.firstImageUrl)){
                cell.secondImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                cell.secondImageView.layer.borderWidth = 4
                cell.firstImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
                cell.tapRight.isEnabled = false
                cell.tapLeft.isEnabled = true
            }
            else if (votedLeftPosts.contains(post.firstImageUrl)){
                cell.firstImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                cell.firstImageView.layer.borderWidth = 4
                
                cell.secondImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
                cell.tapLeft.isEnabled = false
                cell.tapRight.isEnabled = true
            }
            
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

I felt that the biggest issue would probably be the three images that are loaded into the cell but I am utilizing caching and when I commented out their loading I experienced the same issue. I have also read that utilizing a model can help which I believe that I did with the `PostStruct` object. I think I may need to pre-fetch however I cannot figure out where to even start with that. How can I improve my function so that scrolling in my app is smoother?

Comment: Not a full answer, but it also looks like you're loading data out of your database on every single time that you create a cell. This fetch is probably really expensive. Can you load all of your data up-front so you don't have to perform expensive fetches with every single row?

Comment: That is one hell of a `cellForRow` method. Typically, this method should be reserved for cell injection once data is in hand. If you're instantiating databases in them (which you are) then I would rethink the overall approach. Can you grab at least the data up front before loading the table and handle image downloading in post?

Comment: @MJ-12 Could the data loading upfront be done in the ```viewDidLoad``` method?

Comment: When the user opens this particular screen, why don't you load the data in a method like `viewDidLoad` (although sometimes this can actually be too early which is why I usually go for `viewWillAppear`) and then reload the table when it's ready? You can configure the default UI to reflect that data is on its way.

Comment: @MJ-12 I will give this a try, though I just realized that the slowness was being caused by not loading the profile pic using the SDWebImage library.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great place to use the Instruments tool. Run the time profiler on your app as you scroll through your table view. It will show you where the bulk of the delay is coming from.

Where are your images coming from? Are they loading from your local file system, or are those URLs network URLS?

You might need to refactor your code to return cells without the images, and trigger async code that loads the images in a background thread, installs them into your model, and then updates the cell once the images have finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this line of code was the issue:

```
if post.userPic == "" {
                userPic =
                    "Placeholder"
            } else{
                userPic = post.userPic
            }
            let url = URL(string: userPic)
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
            cell.profilePic.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

In stead I changed it to utilize SDWebImage like the other two images in the post.

Comment: You have several issues.  One is that you are accessing Firebase data in the cellForRowAt delegate method.